# Facets not recognized

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am new to elastic4s , I am trying to execute this [example](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/guide/search.md)

```
client execute {
  search in "places"->"cities" query "london" facets (
    facet terms "landmark" field "type",
    facet range "age" field "year" range (1000->1200) to(1200) from(1400)
  )
}
```

however it seems that facets are not recognized by the IDE .
I might be missing an import or dependency
I am using

```
"com.sksamuel.elastic4s"  %% "elastic4s-core"                     % 2.4.0,
"com.sksamuel.elastic4s"  %% "elastic4s-streams"                  % 2.4.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ES 2.4.x, you should use aggregations instead of facets which have been removed in ES 2.0.

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/guide/search.md#aggregations). So in your case you need to change your code to:

```
client.execute {
  search in "places" / "cities" query "london" aggregations(
    aggregation terms "landmark" field "type",
    aggregation range "age" field "year" range (1000, 1200) to(1200) 
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, BTW , is there an option to get all values of specific field ?

Comment: Yes, you can add `size 0` to the terms aggregation, but the performance might suffer if the cardinality of that field is big. Maybe start with 100 and see how it goes.